# EXE created by ant build on execution directly getting installed in TEMP path

Tags: inno-setup, exe

Created an  .exe file from ant build using Inno Setup. While executing the exe file its directly displaying Ready to install screen rather i want a FileChooser where to install the exe file. Do I need to change anything in inno setup scripts before creating the exe file? Please help.

Thanks.